# How to delete sealed column in SPD 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How to delete the sealed column from my list in SharePoint 2013.Using SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete the sealed column directly from SharePoint list using SharePoint designer.

### Using PowerShell

Try this below Commands in SharePoint Management Shell to remove the sealed property of the column and then delete the column.

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://host.domain/sites/sitename"
$web = $site.OpenWeb("/Url/To/Web/Containing/List")
$list = $web.Lists["List Name Here"]
$field = $list.Fields["Field Name Here"]
$field.AllowDeletion = "true"
$field.Sealed = "false"
$field.Delete()
$list.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

---

### Using SharePoint Manager Tool

1. Run the SharePoint Manager Tool in your machine (you can download it
   [here](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/51438#DownloadId=146573))
2. Go to Content Service -> Web Applications -> Your Site -> Site
   Collection -> Your Site Collection Url -> Fields
3. Expand the Field list and select the relevant field
4. On the right hand side pane you can see the field properties.
5. Find AllowDeletion property and set it to true.
6. Find Sealed property and set it to false.
7. Then right click on the field on the left pane and click Delete.
8. That’s it!

**Reference:**

- http://brian-horning.com/removing-sealed-site-columns-from-sharepoint-2010-lists/
- http://mossknowledge.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-remove-sealed-column-in.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I get this error I get “ Cannot find an SPSite object with Id or Url"

Comment: Are you running PowerShell scripts on your Server? IF not, then You have to run it on same server. And are you using default zone url whose entry is created in AAM?

Comment: Yes i am running on my server but still get this errror. This is my site url http://xyz-sharePoint:8041/

Comment: One possible solution you can try is: In IIS, stop and start the SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool.

Comment: Not work  when I try                                                                                                    $web = Get-SPSite "http://host.domain/sites/sitename"  that time it work but after that 2nd line  $list = $web.Lists["List Name Here"] show error "Can not index into a null Array"

Comment: Please try my updated code

Comment: I try this but get error in this line $list = $web.Lists["List Name Here"] "Can not index into a null Array"

Comment: Please check my updated code

Comment: Can i use same this line $web = $site.OpenWeb("/Url/To/Web/Containing/List") ?

Comment: Use  `$web = $site.OpenWeb("url of the web which contains your list")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49707/discussion-between-admin-and-dikesh-gandhi).